# How to link Javascript with HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, random

Hej!

I have this code (**just an example**):

```
function random(min, max) {
    return min + parseInt(Math.random() * (max-min+1));
}
function getKey(length, charset) {
    var key = "";
    while(length--) {
        key += charset[random(0, charset.length-1)];
    }
    return key;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var key = getKey(16, "0123456789ABCDEF");
});
```

And want to "link" this (*javascript*) to a **input[type="submit"]-form** (*html*). So, if I clicked the button he generates each time a new "key".

Can you please find with me a solution? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/faSBr/)

This uses a little bit of jQuery to update the return from `getKey`, which I have renamed `generateKey` for readability.

New additional code:

```
function getNewKey() {
    $('#key').text(generateKey(16, "0123456789ABCDEF"));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getNewKey();
    $('form').on('submit', function(ev){
        getNewKey();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Best answer without alerts ;) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function random(min, max) {
            return min + parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
        }

        function getKey(length, charset) {
            var key = "";
            while (length--) {
                key += charset[random(0, charset.length - 1)];
            }
            return key;
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ipt').click(function () {
                var key = getKey(16, "0123456789ABCDEF");
                alert(key);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="ipt" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#key-generator').click(function() {
    key = getKey(length, charset);
    alert(key);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmP9m/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a button with id `new_key` into your HTML code

```
 <button id="new_key" type="button">New key!</button>
```

And your javascript code

```
function random(min, max) {
    return min + parseInt(Math.random() * (max-min+1));
}
function getKey(length, charset) {
    var key = "";
    while(length--) {
        key += charset[random(0, charset.length-1)];
    }
    return key;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var key = getKey(16, "0123456789ABCDEF");

    $( '#new_key' ).click( function(){
        key = getKey(16, "0123456789ABCDEF");
        alert( key );
    });
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nohponex/JECWC/2/